Finishing with hand lettering
I am beginning work on a custom virtual organ console. The console is minimal in size, and the keyboard cheeks are going to be made from black walnut. On one of the sides, I want to hand letter the word Stevie (The name of the organ. Yes, I name my instruments, so what?) in gold paint. I want the wood to be finished with a matte finish. How, or in what order, should I finish it? I believe that painting the letters and then finishing the wood would be the best idea, but I am unsure. What would be the best approach?

Good question.  Who ever answers this - hopefully your answer will also apply to all instances where lettering, numbering or all sorts of marking is desirable.


I believe that painting the letters and then finishing the wood would be the best idea, but I am unsure.

I think this would be highly preferable.
All finishes fail given enough time, leading to the expectation of future restoration — more specifically, removal of and reapplication of the clear finish rather than a restoration per se. Given this I think it's easy to argue that ideally one does not want the paint on top of the clear finish, but under it.
The paint being below the clearcoat means it is afforded protection by it. And there is anyway the potential for adhesion issues between paint and clear finish (even if the clearcoat does have a matte surface which provides microtexture for a paint the cling to).
So in summary:

Better future-proofs the lettering if restoration is ever undertaken.
The clear finish additionally protects the lettering.
Paint underneath sidesteps potential adhesion issues.

